Pydub Syntax Warning Invalid Escape Sequence
I am getting the warning invalid escape sequence '(' when trying to convert an OGG to MP3 using pydub with FFMPEG in lambda
This is the code that is being executed
key = 'sample.ogg'
    
input_bucket = 'all-formats-input-bucket'
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=input_bucket, Key=key)
audio_data = obj['Body'].read()
    
audio = AudioSegment.from_file(io.BytesIO(audio_data), format="ogg")

This is the code in pydub utils.py relevant to the warning
for token in extra_info[stream['index']]:
    m = re.match('([su]([0-9]{1,2})p?) \(([0-9]{1,2}) bit\)$', token)
    m2 = re.match('([su]([0-9]{1,2})p?)( \(default\))?$', token)
    if m:
        set_property(stream, 'sample_fmt', m.group(1))
        set_property(stream, 'bits_per_sample', int(m.group(2)))
        set_property(stream, 'bits_per_raw_sample', int(m.group(3)))
    elif m2:
        set_property(stream, 'sample_fmt', m2.group(1))
        set_property(stream, 'bits_per_sample', int(m2.group(2)))
        set_property(stream, 'bits_per_raw_sample', int(m2.group(2)))
    elif re.match('(flt)p?( \(default\))?$', token):
        set_property(stream, 'sample_fmt', token)
        set_property(stream, 'bits_per_sample', 32)
        set_property(stream, 'bits_per_raw_sample', 32)
    elif re.match('(dbl)p?( \(default\))?$', token):
        set_property(stream, 'sample_fmt', token)
        set_property(stream, 'bits_per_sample', 64)
        set_property(stream, 'bits_per_raw_sample', 64)
return info

This is the full warning output
/opt/python/pydub/utils.py:292: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
m = re.match("([su]([0-9]{1,2})p?) \(([0-9]{1,2}) bit\)$", token)
/opt/python/pydub/utils.py:293: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
m2 = re.match("([su]([0-9]{1,2})p?)( \(default\))?$", token)
/opt/python/pydub/utils.py:302: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
elif re.match("(flt)p?( \(default\))?$", token):
/opt/python/pydub/utils.py:306: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
elif re.match("(dbl)p?( \(default\))?$", token):

The file conversion is successfully and outputs the correct file. Can someone advise on how much this warning needs to be resolved and how it can be resolved?

You need to make all of those regular expressions raw string literals - r"whatever" - so that Python doesn't try to interpret the backslashes.

@jasonharper Is the issue with the pydub code instead of mine and is there anything I can do with my code or the files I'm processing to resolve the warning? Also, do you know if there is there a way to supress the warning?
